# Does this board do anything else than exposing D+,D- and Vcc,Gnd to some plugs?

Tags: usb, usb-device

I disassembled a JBL Flip 4 blutooth speaker and put out its micro-usb board. I found an image of the bottom
[image]

and of the top
[image]

on [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/202637459700). I have also made an image of my board, but it's full of glue.
[image]

So my question to more experienced electricians than me:

> Does this micro-usb board do anything else, than identifying as a device (not host) and exposing the standard Usb pins (D+, D-, Vcc, Gnd) to these small plugs?

Help would be very appreciated, thank you for your time!

Comment: You mix electricians with electrical engineers. And the board cannot identify itself as an USB device, it is the job of the chip where the USB data pins go to. And since there are capacitors (if they even are capacitors, usually there would be some ESD protection diodes) so the board does a little something so it does not just connect USB connector pins to other connectors.

Comment: @Justme fully agreeing with all you said, but the components *are* labeled C...; I'd have understood one from VBUS to GND, but it seems there's two, and at least one of them is actually from some signal to the ground plane, so no capacitive coupling, either. Best guess: there's never actually any data communication happening here, the USB port is just connected to some resistors for charging, and for some obscure reason these caps improved EMI performance.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Likely the two components are from USB data pins to GND plane. Sure they are labeled as capacitors, which they could be, but the black colour is not typical for a capacitor and it would be more typical for a TVS diode or other ESD protection component.

Comment: sorry, english is my seond language. As mentioned [here](https://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/micro_usb_pinout.shtml): "The device with the 5-pin connector has a pullup to high on the connector. Low (small value resistor to ground or connection to ground) if you are connecting an accessory that the device must ask as a host for. Let it remain high (no-connect) for a connection that the device should remain in normal (slave/client/peripheral) mode for." So I thought this may be accomplished by the board.

Comment: @sebay while technically possible, there's no good reason to do it on that board. Putting ESD protection there does make a lot of sense, though.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you are right, this port is only for charging. But what are the other two pins for?

Comment: If they are resistors, they cannot cause the board to identify as USB device. A resistor is only needed to indicate to host that something is plugged in, but this resistor would not be on this board and even if it were there would be only one resistor. Since you are the one who took the device apart, you would know if only one or both connectors were used. We can't know if both were used or not.

Comment: @Justme both connectors were used. There is a [guide on ifixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/JBL+Flip+4+USB+Port+Replacement/114459) which offers more insight to the interior. Thanks to all of you people. Your help is much appreciated